# Varying number of nested loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a question about varying number of for loops in Matlab. I have generated some different data folders, each one contain some .mat files. The thing I need to do is to generate all possible combinations from those files in those folders (but not the files in the same folder). So basically the algorithm is :

```
For i = 1: number of files in folder 1
  For j = 1:number of files in folder 2
    ............................
      For m = 1: number of files in folder n
        Read file i in folder 1
        Read file j in folder 2
        ......................
        Read file m in folder n
        Result file = sum of data in those files %at last we have n-Dimension matrix

      end;
   end;
 end;
```

If we can fix the number of folders, this is done, but the number of folder varies depend on the input parameter, so I cannot find a suitable solution. 
I also have read about the recursive algorithm but this is not clear to me how to do this.
For eg, using recursive algorithm:

I have a vector that shows number of files in each folder A =[2,3,4] (3 folders).

```
Function Recursive (n, A) % n = 3
  if (n>1)
    Recursive (n-1, A)
  else
    for i = 1: A(n)
     Read file i in folder n;
    end;
  end
```

Here we cannot know previous variable (j,k..), so this is useless.

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: How is your folder structure organized? 
`Main > folder01, folder02` etc... or do you have (variably) nested folders, i.e. `main > folder01 > folder0101; main > folder02, main > folder03 > fodler0301 > folder030101` etc...? In the former case, a single loop is enough.

Comment: Seems like a lot of repetitive reading. Is there too much data to read it all in at once, and then do your computation loops?

Comment: Hi, the structure is Main --> folder01, folder02....., folder n. Number of folders is variable, number of files in each folder also varies. I have a vector so save this information (eg. A = [ 2, 4,5 ]), means there are 2 files in folder 1, 4 files in folder 2, etc.

Comment: For a very different application, involving optimizing a given code, i am having the very same problem of requiring a varying number of nested loops....

Comment: I think the solution could be first generating a MATRIX of all the possible combinations, and after that, create a simple loop for processing all the choices. This exchanges the complexity m nested loops of length n onto a single loop of m.n length. Which is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, reading is **slow**. You shouldn't do it any more than you absolutely have to. If you can freely store everything in memory, do that. If you can't, but if you're actually doing something like summing data in files, calculate the sums of each of the files and store them (probably in a cell with one vector per folder). You also want to do that (work with summary statistics not whole .mat files) if you're calling functions recursively - you don't want to pour your whole .mat files into a new function for every iteration of the innermost loop.

For the actual loop, I would suggest using a main loop with its counter going from 1 to the product of the numbers of files in each folder. Inside that loop, I would test to see what I was updating. Something like

```
BigOutputArray=zeros(A);
P=prod(A);
cumprod=cumprod(A);
S=zeros(n,1);    
currindex=num2cell(ones(n,1));
for ii=1:n
    S(ii)=SumsOfMatFiles{ii}(1);
end
for ii=1:prod(A)
    jj=max([0,find(~mod(ii,P))])+1;
    thissum=sum(S);
    BigOutputArray(i)=thissum;
    S(jj)=SumsOfMatFiles{jj}(currindex(ii)+1);
    currindex(ii)=currindex(ii)+1;
end
```

This assumes SumsOfMatFiles is a nice cell containing n arrays containing the sums, and there's no interaction between the .mat files. If it isn't, replace S with a cell array containing n sets of .mat file contents, and replace sum(S) with the appropriate function, if necessary using S{:}.

Answer (score 0):

I am in favor of converting `m` dynamic nested loop, each one of length `n`:

```
for i1=v{1}
   ...
      for im=v{m}
         f(i1,...,im)=F(i1,...,im);
      end
   ...
end
```

Into a `m*n` list of combinations:

```
I=combvec(v{1},...,v{m}); 
for i=I
   f(i)=F(I(i));
end
f=reshape(F,m,n);
```

`v` is a variable size cell with `m` elements, defining the elements of the loop. `v{i}` is the index row vector for the ith loop.

The loop index could not neccesarily be of a fixed length `n`. The code is the same for that case, as it can be seen.

Both results return a matrix `f` of `m` by `n`.

The central cost is always to evaluate the function `F`, which must take a dynamic number of arguments.

Both loops are *O(n^m)* in complexity, but the dynamic loop cannot be programmed in any known way up to date without recursion.

Both the cost of processing and storing the index `I` and the dynamic loop are insignificant compared with evaluating the function `F`.